# How can I Profile a kernel over time with CUPTI?

Tags: cuda, profiling

I am going to profile over time with the help of CUPTI profiler of some of the benchmark kernels in the CUDA sample SDK (for example matrixMul and dxtc and ...). But CUPTI Profiller returns a value of zero. Is it because the kernels are small? Because when I use a larger kernel, it returns some non-zero values for, say, IPC. I set the time interval between two samples to 70 milliseconds.

The question is, can a small or medium kernel be profiled over time with CUPTI? If yes. How?

Answer (score 1):

[CUPTI](https://docs.nvidia.com/cupti/index.html) includes a number of [sample codes](https://docs.nvidia.com/cupti/r_main.html#r_samples).  One that appears fairly similar to your request:

> for, say, IPC

is **callback_metric**:

> This sample shows how to use both the callback and metric APIs to record the metric's events during the execution of a simple kernel, and then use those events to calculate the metric value.

On a typical linux install, this sample code would be located at: `/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/samples/callback_metric/`

and the sample includes just a single source file and a Makefile.

As it happens, this sample code actually computes the IPC metric (by default, if no command line arguments are specified), and does it on a very short/simple kernel:

```
__global__ void VecAdd(const int* A, const int* B, int* C, int N)
{
  int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
  if (i < N)
    C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
}
```

And here is the output, on a V100:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64 ./callback_metric
Usage: ./callback_metric [device_num] [metric_name]
CUDA Device Number: 0
CUDA Device Name: Tesla V100-PCIE-32GB
Compute Capability of Device: 7.0
Launching kernel: blocks 196, thread/block 256
Pass 0
Launching kernel: blocks 196, thread/block 256
        inst_executed = 25043 (384, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 339, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 256, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 256, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 256, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 384, 256, 256, 256)
        inst_executed (normalized) (25043 * 80) / 80 = 25043
        active_cycles = 126682 (1670, 1502, 1665, 1543, 1615, 1457, 1654, 1573, 1632, 1533, 1661, 1540, 1583, 1482, 1667, 1522, 1652, 1523, 1607, 1477, 1681, 1576, 1636, 1564, 1657, 1553, 1621, 1506, 1690, 1548, 1636, 1544, 1564, 1455, 1691, 1644, 1594, 1501, 1700, 1573, 1647, 1455, 1677, 1553, 1638, 1497, 1516, 1429, 1694, 1637, 1670, 1487, 1688, 1555, 1692, 1503, 1669, 1551, 1614, 1523, 1699, 1599, 1647, 1505, 1692, 1556, 1599, 1498, 1641, 1535, 1616, 1475, 1659, 1591, 1614, 1419, 1631, 1513, 1559, 1447)
        active_cycles (normalized) (126682 * 80) / 80 = 126682
Metric ipc = 0.197684
$
```

For reference, here is the full sample code:

```
/*
 * Copyright 2011-2017 NVIDIA Corporation. All rights reserved
 *
 * Sample app to demonstrate use of CUPTI library to obtain metric values
 * using callbacks for CUDA runtime APIs
 *
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cupti.h>

#define METRIC_NAME "ipc"

#define DRIVER_API_CALL(apiFuncCall)                                           \
do {                                                                           \
    CUresult _status = apiFuncCall;                                            \
    if (_status != CUDA_SUCCESS) {                                             \
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: error: function %s failed with error %d.\n",   \
                __FILE__, __LINE__, #apiFuncCall, _status);                    \
        exit(-1);                                                              \
    }                                                                          \
} while (0)

#define RUNTIME_API_CALL(apiFuncCall)                                          \
do {                                                                           \
    cudaError_t _status = apiFuncCall;                                         \
    if (_status != cudaSuccess) {                                              \
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: error: function %s failed with error %s.\n",   \
                __FILE__, __LINE__, #apiFuncCall, cudaGetErrorString(_status));\
        exit(-1);                                                              \
    }                                                                          \
} while (0)

#define CUPTI_CALL(call)                                                \
  do {                                                                  \
    CUptiResult _status = call;                                         \
    if (_status != CUPTI_SUCCESS) {                                     \
      const char *errstr;                                               \
      cuptiGetResultString(_status, &errstr);                           \
      fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: error: function %s failed with error %s.\n", \
              __FILE__, __LINE__, #call, errstr);                       \
      exit(-1);                                                         \
    }                                                                   \
  } while (0)

#define ALIGN_SIZE (8)
#define ALIGN_BUFFER(buffer, align)                                            \
  (((uintptr_t) (buffer) & ((align)-1)) ? ((buffer) + (align) - ((uintptr_t) (buffer) & ((align)-1))) : (buffer))

// User data for event collection callback
typedef struct MetricData_st {
  // the device where metric is being collected
  CUdevice device;
  // the set of event groups to collect for a pass
  CUpti_EventGroupSet *eventGroups;
  // the current number of events collected in eventIdArray and
  // eventValueArray
  uint32_t eventIdx;
  // the number of entries in eventIdArray and eventValueArray
  uint32_t numEvents;
  // array of event ids
  CUpti_EventID *eventIdArray;
  // array of event values
  uint64_t *eventValueArray;
} MetricData_t;

static uint64_t kernelDuration;

// Device code
__global__ void VecAdd(const int* A, const int* B, int* C, int N)
{
  int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
  if (i < N)
    C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
}

static void
initVec(int *vec, int n)
{
  for (int i=0; i< n; i++)
    vec[i] = i;
}

void CUPTIAPI
getMetricValueCallback(void *userdata, CUpti_CallbackDomain domain,
                       CUpti_CallbackId cbid, const CUpti_CallbackData *cbInfo)
{
  MetricData_t *metricData = (MetricData_t*)userdata;
  unsigned int i, j, k;

  // This callback is enabled only for launch so we shouldn't see
  // anything else.
  if ((cbid != CUPTI_RUNTIME_TRACE_CBID_cudaLaunch_v3020) &&
      (cbid != CUPTI_RUNTIME_TRACE_CBID_cudaLaunchKernel_v7000))
  {
    printf("%s:%d: unexpected cbid %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, cbid);
    exit(-1);
  }

  // on entry, enable all the event groups being collected this pass,
  // for metrics we collect for all instances of the event
  if (cbInfo->callbackSite == CUPTI_API_ENTER) {
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    CUPTI_CALL(cuptiSetEventCollectionMode(cbInfo->context,
                                           CUPTI_EVENT_COLLECTION_MODE_KERNEL));

    for (i = 0; i < metricData->eventGroups->numEventGroups; i++) {
      uint32_t all = 1;
      CUPTI_CALL(cuptiEventGroupSetAttribute(metricData->eventGroups->eventGroups[i],
                                             CUPTI_EVENT_GROUP_ATTR_PROFILE_ALL_DOMAIN_INSTANCES,
                                             sizeof(all), &all));
      CUPTI_CALL(cuptiEventGroupEnable(metricData->eventGroups->eventGroups[i]));
    }
  }

  // on exit, read and record event values
  if (cbInfo->callbackSite == CUPTI_API_EXIT) {
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    // for each group, read the event values from the group and record
    // in metricData
    for (i = 0; i < metricData->eventGroups->numEventGroups; i++) {
      CUpti_EventGroup group = metricData->eventGroups->eventGroups[i];
      CUpti_EventDomainID groupDomain;
      uint32_t numEvents, numInstances, numTotalInstances;
      CUpti_EventID *eventIds;
      size_t groupDomainSize = sizeof(groupDomain);
      size_t numEventsSize = sizeof(numEvents);
      size_t numInstancesSize = sizeof(numInstances);
      size_t numTotalInstancesSize = sizeof(numTotalInstances);
      uint64_t *values, normalized, *sum;
      size_t valuesSize, eventIdsSize;
      size_t numCountersRead = 0;

      CUPTI_CALL(cuptiEventGroupGetAttribute(group,
                                             CUPTI_EVENT_GROUP_ATTR_EVENT_DOMAIN_ID,
                                             &groupDomainSize, &groupDomain));
      CUPTI_CALL(cuptiDeviceGetEventDomainAttribute(metricData->device, groupDomain,
                                                    CUPTI_EVENT_DOMAIN_ATTR_TOTAL_INSTANCE_COUNT,
                                                    &numTotalInstancesSize, &numTotalInstances));
      CUPTI_CALL(cuptiEventGroupGetAttribute(group,
                                             CUPTI_EVENT_GROUP_ATTR_INSTANCE_COUNT,
                                             &numInstancesSize, &numInstances));
      CUPTI_CALL(cuptiEventGroupGetAttribute(group,
                                             CUPTI_EVENT_GROUP_ATTR_NUM_EVENTS,
                                             &numEventsSize, &numEvents));
      eventIdsSize = numEvents * sizeof(CUpti_EventID);
      eventIds = (CUpti_EventID *)malloc(eventIdsSize);
      CUPTI_CALL(cuptiEventGroupGetAttribute(group,
                                             CUPTI_EVENT_GROUP_ATTR_EVENTS,
                                             &eventIdsSize, eventIds));

      valuesSize = sizeof(uint64_t) * numInstances * numEvents;
      values = (uint64_t *)malloc(valuesSize);

      CUPTI_CALL(cuptiEventGroupReadAllEvents(group,
                                          CUPTI_EVENT_READ_FLAG_NONE,
                                          &valuesSize,
                                          values,
                                          &eventIdsSize,
                                          eventIds,
                                          &numCountersRead));

      if (metricData->eventIdx >= metricData->numEvents) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: too many events collected, metric expects only %d\n",
                (int)metricData->numEvents);
        exit(-1);
      }

      sum = (uint64_t *)calloc(sizeof(uint64_t), numEvents);
      // sum collect event values from all instances
      for (k = 0; k < numInstances; k++) {
        for (j = 0; j < numEvents; j++) {
            sum[j] += values[(k * numEvents) + j];
        }
      }

      for (j = 0; j < numEvents; j++) {
        // normalize the event value to represent the total number of
        // domain instances on the device
        normalized = (sum[j] * numTotalInstances) / numInstances;

        metricData->eventIdArray[metricData->eventIdx] = eventIds[j];
        metricData->eventValueArray[metricData->eventIdx] = normalized;
        metricData->eventIdx++;

        // print collected value
        {
          char eventName[128];
          size_t eventNameSize = sizeof(eventName) - 1;
          CUPTI_CALL(cuptiEventGetAttribute(eventIds[j], CUPTI_EVENT_ATTR_NAME,
                                            &eventNameSize, eventName));
          eventName[127] = '\0';
          printf("\t%s = %llu (", eventName, (unsigned long long)sum[j]);
          if (numInstances > 1) {
            for (k = 0; k < numInstances; k++) {
              if (k != 0)
                printf(", ");
              printf("%llu", (unsigned long long)values[(k * numEvents) + j]);
            }
          }

          printf(")\n");
          printf("\t%s (normalized) (%llu * %u) / %u = %llu\n",
                 eventName, (unsigned long long)sum[j],
                 numTotalInstances, numInstances,
                 (unsigned long long)normalized);
        }
      }

      free(values);
      free(sum);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < metricData->eventGroups->numEventGroups; i++)
      CUPTI_CALL(cuptiEventGroupDisable(metricData->eventGroups->eventGroups[i]));
  }
}

static void
cleanUp(int *h_A, int *h_B, int *h_C, int *d_A, int *d_B, int *d_C)
{
  if (d_A)
    cudaFree(d_A);
  if (d_B)
    cudaFree(d_B);
  if (d_C)
    cudaFree(d_C);

  // Free host memory
  if (h_A)
    free(h_A);
  if (h_B)
    free(h_B);
  if (h_C)
    free(h_C);
}

static void
runPass()
{
  int N = 50000;
  size_t size = N * sizeof(int);
  int threadsPerBlock = 0;
  int blocksPerGrid = 0;
  int *h_A, *h_B, *h_C;
  int *d_A, *d_B, *d_C;
  int i, sum;

  // Allocate input vectors h_A and h_B in host memory
  h_A = (int*)malloc(size);
  h_B = (int*)malloc(size);
  h_C = (int*)malloc(size);

  // Initialize input vectors
  initVec(h_A, N);
  initVec(h_B, N);
  memset(h_C, 0, size);

  // Allocate vectors in device memory
  cudaMalloc((void**)&d_A, size);
  cudaMalloc((void**)&d_B, size);
  cudaMalloc((void**)&d_C, size);

  // Copy vectors from host memory to device memory
  cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_B, h_B, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  // Invoke kernel
  threadsPerBlock = 256;
  blocksPerGrid = (N + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;
  printf("Launching kernel: blocks %d, thread/block %d\n",
         blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock);

  VecAdd<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C, N);

  // Copy result from device memory to host memory
  // h_C contains the result in host memory
  cudaMemcpy(h_C, d_C, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  // Verify result
  for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    sum = h_A[i] + h_B[i];
    if (h_C[i] != sum) {
      fprintf(stderr, "error: result verification failed\n");
      exit(-1);
    }
  }

  cleanUp(h_A, h_B, h_C, d_A, d_B, d_C);
}

static void CUPTIAPI
bufferRequested(uint8_t **buffer, size_t *size, size_t *maxNumRecords)
{
  uint8_t *rawBuffer;

  *size = 16 * 1024;
  rawBuffer = (uint8_t *)malloc(*size + ALIGN_SIZE);

  *buffer = ALIGN_BUFFER(rawBuffer, ALIGN_SIZE);
  *maxNumRecords = 0;

  if (*buffer == NULL) {
    printf("Error: out of memory\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
}

static void CUPTIAPI
bufferCompleted(CUcontext ctx, uint32_t streamId, uint8_t *buffer, size_t size, size_t validSize)
{
  CUpti_Activity *record = NULL;
  CUpti_ActivityKernel6 *kernel;

  //since we launched only 1 kernel, we should have only 1 kernel record
  CUPTI_CALL(cuptiActivityGetNextRecord(buffer, validSize, &record));

  kernel = (CUpti_ActivityKernel6 *)record;
  if (kernel->kind != CUPTI_ACTIVITY_KIND_KERNEL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: expected kernel activity record, got %d\n", (int)kernel->kind);
    exit(-1);
  }

  kernelDuration = kernel->end - kernel->start;
  free(buffer);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  CUpti_SubscriberHandle subscriber;
  CUcontext context = 0;
  CUdevice device = 0;
  int deviceNum;
  int deviceCount;
  char deviceName[32];
  const char *metricName;
  CUpti_MetricID metricId;
  CUpti_EventGroupSets *passData;
  MetricData_t metricData;
  unsigned int pass;
  CUpti_MetricValue metricValue;

  printf("Usage: %s [device_num] [metric_name]\n", argv[0]);

  // make sure activity is enabled before any CUDA API
  CUPTI_CALL(cuptiActivityEnable(CUPTI_ACTIVITY_KIND_KERNEL));

  DRIVER_API_CALL(cuInit(0));
  DRIVER_API_CALL(cuDeviceGetCount(&deviceCount));
  if (deviceCount == 0) {
    printf("There is no device supporting CUDA.\n");
    return -2;
  }

  if (argc > 1)
    deviceNum = atoi(argv[1]);
  else
    deviceNum = 0;
  printf("CUDA Device Number: %d\n", deviceNum);

  DRIVER_API_CALL(cuDeviceGet(&device, deviceNum));
  DRIVER_API_CALL(cuDeviceGetName(deviceName, 32, device));
  printf("CUDA Device Name: %s\n", deviceName);

  int major, minor;
  DRIVER_API_CALL(cuDeviceGetAttribute(&major, CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPUTE_CAPABILITY_MAJOR, device));
  DRIVER_API_CALL(cuDeviceGetAttribute(&minor, CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPUTE_CAPABILITY_MINOR, device));

  int deviceComputeCapability = 10 * major + minor;
  printf("Compute Capability of Device: %d.%d\n", major,minor);
  if(deviceComputeCapability > 72) {
    printf("Sample unsupported on Device with compute capability > 7.2\n");
    return -2;
  }

  DRIVER_API_CALL(cuCtxCreate(&context, 0, device));

  // Get the name of the metric to collect
  if (argc > 2)
    metricName = argv[2];
  else {
    metricName = METRIC_NAME;
  }

  // need to collect duration of kernel execution without any event
  // collection enabled (some metrics need kernel duration as part of
  // calculation). The only accurate way to do this is by using the
  // activity API.
  {
    CUPTI_CALL(cuptiActivityRegisterCallbacks(bufferRequested, bufferCompleted));
    runPass();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    CUPTI_CALL(cuptiActivityFlushAll(0));
  }

  // setup launch callback for event collection
  CUPTI_CALL(cuptiSubscribe(&subscriber, (CUpti_CallbackFunc)getMetricValueCallback, &metricData));
  CUPTI_CALL(cuptiEnableCallback(1, subscriber, CUPTI_CB_DOMAIN_RUNTIME_API,
                                 CUPTI_RUNTIME_TRACE_CBID_cudaLaunch_v3020));
  CUPTI_CALL(cuptiEnableCallback(1, subscriber, CUPTI_CB_DOMAIN_RUNTIME_API,
                                 CUPTI_RUNTIME_TRACE_CBID_cudaLaunchKernel_v7000));

  // allocate space to hold all the events needed for the metric
  CUPTI_CALL(cuptiMetricGetIdFromName(device, metricName, &metricId));
  CUPTI_CALL(cuptiMetricGetNumEvents(metricId, &metricData.numEvents));
  metricData.device = device;
  metricData.eventIdArray = (CUpti_EventID *)malloc(metricData.numEvents * sizeof(CUpti_EventID));
  metricData.eventValueArray = (uint64_t *)malloc(metricData.numEvents * sizeof(uint64_t));
  metricData.eventIdx = 0;

  // get the number of passes required to collect all the events
  // needed for the metric and the event groups for each pass
  CUPTI_CALL(cuptiMetricCreateEventGroupSets(context, sizeof(metricId), &metricId, &passData));
  for (pass = 0; pass < passData->numSets; pass++) {
    printf("Pass %u\n", pass);
    metricData.eventGroups = passData->sets + pass;
    runPass();
  }

  if (metricData.eventIdx != metricData.numEvents) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error: expected %u metric events, got %u\n",
            metricData.numEvents, metricData.eventIdx);
    exit(-1);
  }

  // use all the collected events to calculate the metric value
  CUPTI_CALL(cuptiMetricGetValue(device, metricId,
                                 metricData.numEvents * sizeof(CUpti_EventID),
                                 metricData.eventIdArray,
                                 metricData.numEvents * sizeof(uint64_t),
                                 metricData.eventValueArray,
                                 kernelDuration, &metricValue));

  // print metric value, we format based on the value kind
  {
    CUpti_MetricValueKind valueKind;
    size_t valueKindSize = sizeof(valueKind);
    CUPTI_CALL(cuptiMetricGetAttribute(metricId, CUPTI_METRIC_ATTR_VALUE_KIND,
                                       &valueKindSize, &valueKind));
    switch (valueKind) {
    case CUPTI_METRIC_VALUE_KIND_DOUBLE:
      printf("Metric %s = %f\n", metricName, metricValue.metricValueDouble);
      break;
    case CUPTI_METRIC_VALUE_KIND_UINT64:
      printf("Metric %s = %llu\n", metricName,
             (unsigned long long)metricValue.metricValueUint64);
      break;
    case CUPTI_METRIC_VALUE_KIND_INT64:
      printf("Metric %s = %lld\n", metricName,
             (long long)metricValue.metricValueInt64);
      break;
    case CUPTI_METRIC_VALUE_KIND_PERCENT:
      printf("Metric %s = %f%%\n", metricName, metricValue.metricValuePercent);
      break;
    case CUPTI_METRIC_VALUE_KIND_THROUGHPUT:
      printf("Metric %s = %llu bytes/sec\n", metricName,
             (unsigned long long)metricValue.metricValueThroughput);
      break;
    case CUPTI_METRIC_VALUE_KIND_UTILIZATION_LEVEL:
      printf("Metric %s = utilization level %u\n", metricName,
             (unsigned int)metricValue.metricValueUtilizationLevel);
      break;
    default:
      fprintf(stderr, "error: unknown value kind\n");
      exit(-1);
    }
  }

  CUPTI_CALL(cuptiUnsubscribe(subscriber));
  return 0;
}
```